# Setting view on previous activity on finish

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I have two activities, activity A has a textview and a button, by pressing the button I will go to activity B. In activity B there contains a editText and a button, after editing editText then clicking on the button in activity B it will then go back to activity a and display the text in the TextView.

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity{

    ...
    public void setText(String text){
           textView.setText(text);
    }

}

public class B extends AppCompatActivity{

    ...
    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        A a = new A();
        a.setText(editText.getText().toString());
        finish();
        }
    });

}
```

however after pressing button in activity B I will get a nullpointerexception. I do not want to change B to a fragment.

Comment: how can you call A a = new A() in B activity? A is an activity not a class. please use intents to transfer data between two activities.

Comment: Use could use intent, interface or a static variable  for it.

Comment: Post stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to do something like this

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity{

    public void goToB_activityBringText(){
       Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
       startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
                 textView.setText(result);
            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
            }
        }
    }
}

public class B extends AppCompatActivity{

    ...
    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent returnIntent = new Intent(); 
        returnIntent.putExtra("result","This is my text value");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        finish();

        }
    });
}
```

**Read full details of startActivityForResult method of Activity**

Answer (score 0):

If you have two activities you need to receive the value from the B activity in A. You can use `startActivityForResult()` and in B send the value you need.

Here you can learn how to use it.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html?hl=es

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that this way. Use intent to pass data through activities. If you want go back from one activity to another and pass data back, you should use result mechanism them (it is also using intents).

Check this , should help you in this case.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

In other words
You have to start activity B with `startActivityForResult` then before finishing it set result and then handle result in activity A within method `onActivityResult`. You can also read more about passing data through intents.

Answer (score 0):

Use `navigateToB` to start Activity `B` and Use `onActivityResult`

**Update Manifest As:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".B"
        android:parentActivityName=".A" />
```

**A.java**

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity{

    public void setText(String text){
        textView.setText(text);
    }

    public void navigateToB() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(data != null) {
            String text = data.getString("TEXT");
            textView.setText(text);
        }
    }   

}
```

**B.java**

```
public class B extends AppCompatActivity{

    ...
    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.putString("TEXT", editText.getText().toString());
            setResult(data, RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```